# Get addressbook group for particular contact

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, addressbook

In my app i am getting contacts like this..

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
for( int i=0;i< nPeople;i++)
{
        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
        CFStringRef firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        .....
        and so on
}
```

can anyone suggest me how to get the group for `nPeople`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following documentation

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABPerson_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ABPerson/parentGroups

There is a method parentGroups which returns the array of groups to which the person belongs...........

Comment: still not getting it, can you please provide some code.... every time app throws an exception

Comment: ABMultiValueRef groups  = ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABGroupNameProperty);
        NSString *groupName;
        for(int k = 0; k < ABMultiValueGetCount(groups); k++){
        
            groupName = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(groups, k);
        
        }          Use this. It may work for you.I am not damn sure about this. But hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks for your help but it's not working in my case, getting random exception at line ABMultiValueGetCount(groups), ive tried some other ways, but also having some problem, you can see my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252366/getting-group-for-particular-contact-from-addressbook-iphone